# How do I setup a subdomain in godaddy.com and point to another server?

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

When I create a subdomain in godaddy.com the only option is to forward that subdomain, and I don't want to forward it, I want it to point to another server. I don't want the main site or the email accounts to be disrupted either.

Currently I have a main site: walkerseo.com and a subdomain: demo.walkerseo.com that is working fine. demo.walkerseo.com is hosted on a static site and walkerseo.com is a website that is hosted within a CMS.

The static hosting people keep pointing to godaddy.com and godaddy.com tells me I have to setup the subdomain at the static hosting place.

I am frustrated and confused and need to get some subdomains setup. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked GoDaddy's support people about this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to set up a Cname record where you need to set up another A record and point that to the IP of the server. You can't use a CNAME because that was designed to point to another domain not point to an IP address , and you are trying to point to an IP. Set up your A record as sub.example.com 192.168.1.2.